# What open source C++ Library can I use to display PDF files in a proprietary closed source application?

Tags: c++, pdf

I am working on a proprietary closed source C++ project that requires a built in PDF viewer. We can use open source but not GPL software. LGPL, MIT, Apache, public style licenses are OK as is any license that allows us to keep the source proprietary and closed. I have had a hard time finding a solution that is either not expensive, restrictive or both.

- PoDoFo handles parsing but not display
- ImageMagick can convert PDF to image but not help with allowing for text selection and hyperlinks.
- Poppler is perfect functionality wise but is GPL so I can't use it
- MuPDF is GPL or too expensive with a paid license

Am I missing something? What do you do when you need PDF in a proprietary C++ application?

Comment: Xpdf (from which poppler was developed) is available with commercial licenses.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that Glyph and Cog is the reseller of such licenses http://www.glyphandcog.com/. What is not clear from the site is that they sell more than just per-user licenses.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Glyph and Cog had a good solution and that's what we ended up going with.

Answer (score 3):

[pdfium](https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/) is a library developped by Google and used within Chromium to render PDFs.

Building it from source can be tricky, but there is a [binary distribution on Github](https://github.com/bblanchon/pdfium-binaries) provided by a third party developer. The project on Github also supplies the scripts used to generate the binaries and one needs only to provide values to a few parameters to build the library themself.

Answer (score 1):

I am developer at Debenu and we just released PDF viewer SDK that might suit you, including your license needs, so you can give it a try.
[Link to Debenu PDF Viewer SDK.](http://www.debenu.com/products/development/debenu-pdf-viewer-sdk/)

Comment: You might want to mention the fact that your product works on Windows only.